# Workaround Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame and ad-hoc solution

Tags: javascript, security, cross-domain

I know this subject has been largely discussed and there is no way to get the parent frame modify the children frame due to security reason.
BUT
I'm developing a ad-hoc solution for some clients, we can configure their browser and eventually install plugin ( which will be the "fail" solution).
We would like to configure the browser (chrome or whatever ) to NOT protect the browser from this.

My aim is to inject a JavaScript into their website without having any access to their website.

I actually use a php proxy which works... pretty bad ( how to keep the links when they are loaded dynamically via JavaScript? ) and I would not like to develop a Firefox plugin because it s a bit heavier and longer to set up I guess.

Any idea?

Comment: i m not sure i ve been very clear. 
I don't want to hack the website, just on the "low security browser" of our client, they will be able to see there website plus our .js that will modify the website.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not that clear. But if you want to load a different domain from the parent in an iframe, there is no way to access it, UNLESS your customer uses an open-source browser and are happy for you to install on their systems a hacked version of the browser that will allow this.

But I can assure you this is not going to happen for a variety of reasons.

tl;dr: you can't.

Comment: well we could do it too. It's a very specific application that will require our client to buy a tablet just to use it. We could install a hacked web browser. I'm actually searching for the simplest solution.

It has to be simple for us to install & develop and allow us to modify via javascript part of the client website without access to ftp.

Answer (score 0):

You can communicate between 2 frames from 2 different domains using [`window.postMessage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.postMessage) for the recent browsers.

If you have to support IE6/IE7 or older browsers, you can use the [`window.name`](http://www.sitepen.com/blog/2008/07/22/windowname-transport/) hack.

Both techniques allow you to pass string data between frames.
You need then to have some javascript on both sides that listen to the event and make the action. You don't need to change anything to the browser configuration.

**EDIT:**

After your comment, here is another option: a [bookmarklet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bookmarklet). You define a page like this on your site, changing the path to the js file:

```
<html>
<body>
<a href="javascript:(function(){var s=document.createElement('SCRIPT');s.src='/url/to/your.js?'+(Math.random());document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(s);})()">Drag'n Drop this to your bookmarks</a>
</body>
</html>
```

And you ask your users to click the bookmark when they want your code to run.
This will inject the code in the client page, and you are free to do what you want.

Obviously this has a security concern. Your script has full access(content, cookies) in their page. But since you are almost ready to recompile a web browsers for that :) I guess it will work for them.

Comment: i don't need to support old browser.
If i understand well, frames can communicate to each other?
For instance frame A send a message to frame B But frame B has the javascript that listen the postMessage event. My client website can't be modified to listen anything.

In my case i would like frame A (mine) to modify Frame B (client)  but i have no control on what is in frame B. Wich is not allowed by browser ( would be a weakness). Our chance is that we can modify the settings of the client browser (it s not a large scale application).

thx for your time and patience!

Comment: I'm not sure i understood. 
How it s injecting the code in the Iframe? This exemple will inject the script in the head on the main frame no?

Comment: The user has to drag and drop the link to their bookmark bar (if this is acceptable for them). Then they go to the client page. Click the bookmark, at this time your js script is loaded from your site inside their page. You can then add an iframe, change the content,... whatever you want. But you need their manual action(and consent) to inject your external script.